# How to implement a branch-and-bound in a functional programming language?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp

I am trying to write a branch and bound search on the set of all functions f: D -> R, where the domain size is small (|D| ~ 20) and the range is much bigger (|R| ~ 2^20). Initially, I came up with the following solution.

```
(builder (domain range condlist partial-map)
            (let ((passed? (check condlist partial-map)))
              (cond
               ((not passed?) nil)
               (domain (recur-on-first domain range condlist partial-map '()))
               (t partial-map))))
(recur-on-first (domain range condlist partial-map ignored)
                   (cond
                    ((null range) nil)
                    (t (let ((first-to-first
                              (builder (cdr domain)
                                       (append ignored (cdr range))
                                       condlist
                                       (cons (cons (car domain) (car range)) partial-map))))
                         (or first-to-first
                             (recur-on-first domain
                                             (cdr range)
                                             condlist
                                             partial-map
                                             (cons (car range) ignored))))))))
```

Here the parameter `condlist` to the function `builder` is a list of conditions that should be satisfied by a solution. The function `check` returns nil iff any element in the list of conditions is violated by the `partial-map`. The function `recur-on-first` assigns the first element in the domain to the first element in the range and tries to build a solution from there. Failing this `recur-on-first` invokes itself to try and construct a solution that assigns the first element in the domain to some element other than the first one in the range. However, it has to maintain a list `ignored` that stores these discarded elements (like the first element in the range) as they could be images of some other elements in the domain.

There are two problems that I can see with this solution. The first one is that the lists `ignored` and `range` in the function `recur-on-first` are quite large and `append`ing them is an expensive operation. The second problem is that the recursion depth of the solution depends on the size of the range.

So I came up with the following solution that uses doubly linked lists to store the elements in the range. The functions `start`, `next` and `end` provide facilities to iterate over the doubly linked list.

```
(builder (domain range condlist &optional (partial-map nil))
            (block builder
                   (let ((passed? (check condlist partial-map)))
                     (cond
                       ((not passed?) nil)
                       (domain (let* ((cur (start range))
                                      (prev (dbl-node-prev cur)))
                                 (loop
                                   (if (not (end cur))
                                     (progn
                                       (splice-out range cur)
                                       (let ((sol (builder (cdr domain)
                                                           range
                                                           condlist
                                                           (cons (cons (car domain) (data cur)) partial-map))))
                                         (splice-in range prev cur)
                                         (if sol (return-from builder sol)))
                                       (setq prev cur)
                                       (setq cur (next cur)))
                                     (return-from builder nil)))))
                       (t partial-map))))))
```

The runtime of the second solution is much better than the runtime of the first solution. The `append` operation in the first solution is replaced by splicing elements in and out of a doubly linked list (these operations are constant time) and the recursion depth only depends on the size of the domain. But my problem with this solution is that it uses `C` style code. So my question is this.

Is there a solution that is as efficient as the second solution but does not use `setf`s and mutable data structures? In other words, is there an efficient functional programming solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First idea that comes to mind: use the same general approach, but replace the loop with a tail-recursive call whose parameter is the spliced list for the next stage of the computation?  You never have to modify the spliced list, just generate a new list at each stage.  This admittedly is not constant-time, but you need to walk the list to find where to splice anyway.  It might even be able to re-use most of the nodes, especially if you can use a singly-linked list.